# PHP MySQL join help

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have **3 tables**, companies, industries and company_industry.

In companies, I store information about companies and in industries there's some common industries to attach to the company. So in the table company_industry I store the ID of the company and the industry.

My problem is that I want to do a fulltext search of the company including the industry. I know it has something to do with join, but this is far to advanced than I can handle.

Comment: You can't make a fulltext index across multiple tables, so you'll need to denormalize your data, (reproduce information found in one table in another) if that is what you're using.

Comment: but can't I just do MATCH(....) AGAINST(...) or MATCH(industry) AGAINST(...). That should work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full text search I'm not so sure about, but the JOIN is fairly easy.

```
SELECT * FROM company JOIN company_industry ON company.id = company_industry.company JOIN industry ON company_industry.industry = industry.id;
```

As a side note, unless a company can be part of multiple industries, the company_industry table is not required.